# How to append new rows to a table more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a table within a form that I want to append new rows as the user enters input in the last row of the table.

```
$('table.form-table').on('input', function() {
    var tableID = '#' + $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    if(jQuery(this).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
        var currTR = $(this).closest('tr');
        var currTRhtml = '<tr>' + currTR.html() + '</tr>';
        var nextRow = jQuery(currTRhtml);

        var checkBox = jQuery('<td class="border-right checks"><input type="checkbox" name="del_000" value="000"></td>');
        jQuery(tableID).append(nextRow);
        checkBox.appendTo(currTR);
    }   
});
```

And the html code if needed (simplified/trimmed):

```
<table class="form-table"  id="XXX" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<thead>
    <tr class="main"><th nowrap colspan="3" align="left" 
        class="border-left border-top border-right">
        <h3>XXX</h3></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>header</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
            <tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="isnew" value="">
    <td >
            <input type="text" 
             name="new_text"
             value="">
            </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that this works only once and does not continue appending new rows. It's as if the `last-child` filtering does not get reset...
Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `input` an actual event?

Comment: @KevinBowersox - yes, in newer browsers it is

Comment: yes the .html() was missing...

Comment: Does it work if you replace jQurey with jQuery ?

Comment: You still have syntax errors in your code. `jQuery($(this).closest('table').append(newRow);` looks wrong. Please post your actual code and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo for your problem.

Comment: i did not copy the original code as that one is fairly larger than this. I typed a simplified version and seems like I had typos...

Comment: That's ok, but it should at least be "correct" (i.e. replicate the error exactly) so that we can find out the actual problem.

Comment: sure, i'll add the actual code as well

Comment: Also `this` inside the event handler would be the table, is the table inside a table, if not it probably doesn't have a closest `TR` or `table` (actually the closest table would be itself) ?

Comment: i put the original code work

Comment: But no demo yet. Since the HTML structure might be important as well and this problem seems to involve user interaction, you really should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: I added some the html code if that may be important. can't put all of it or create the demo for proprietary reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use the event's target, rather than "this". Right now "this" refers to the current table, but you need to refer to the current input box and then use closest() to find its parent tr (and :first-child to make sure it's the last one). So your code needs to look more like this:

```
$('table.form-table').on('input', function(e) {
    var tableID = '#' + $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    if ($(e.target).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
        var currTR = $(e.target).closest('tr');
        var currTRhtml = '<tr>' + currTR.html() + '</tr>';
        var nextRow = $(currTRhtml);

        var checkBox = $('<td class="border-right checks"><input type="checkbox" name="del_000" value="000"></td>');
        $(tableID).append(nextRow);
        checkBox.appendTo(currTR);
    }   
});
```

Notice I'm passing the event as "e" and then referencing the current input box with $(e.target).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/2dukx/)'s a working JS fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you need to delegate the `input` event as the appended rows do not exist on `$(document).ready()`. Try doing something like this to delegate the handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.form-table tbody').on('input', 'tr', function () {
        var self = $(this),
            tableID = '#' + self.closest('table').attr('id'),
            currTR = self.closest('tr'),
            currTRhtml = '<tr>' + currTR.html() + '</tr>',
            nextRow = $(currTRhtml),
            checkBox = $('<td class="border-right checks"><input type="checkbox" name="del_000" value="000"></td>');
        if (currTR.is(':last-child')) {
            $(tableID).append(nextRow);
            checkBox.appendTo(currTR);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KW7ET/